# Determining convergence of series of functions with natural logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have to determine the convergence of the series of functions of $\sum f_n$, $f_n:\mathbf R \rightarrow \mathbf R$, defined by:
$$f_n = \biggl(\frac{\ln(1+n^2x^2)}{n}\biggr)^n$$

I do not know how to proceed, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the point of the exercise is to determine: absolute , conditional, pointwise and uniform convergence or any of these.

Comment: What happens when $x=1?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$, it converges.

If $x\ne 0$, it is a positive terms series.

The root test gives
$$\lim_{\infty}\frac {\ln (1+nx^2)}{n}=0$$ since
$$\ln (1+nx^2)\le \sqrt {1+nx^2}$$
and 
$$\sqrt {1+nx^2}=\sqrt {n}\sqrt {x^2+\frac {1}{n}} $$

Thus, it converges for all reals.

Comment: Thank you for your help :D